# "Complex conjugate" of a ComplexImage object, for cross-correlation

Tags: c#, fft, complex-numbers, aforge

I am trying to do cross correlation between two images, using the AForge framework. To do this I need to get the complex conjugate of a `ComplexImage` object.

I didn't find any tool to do this in the AForge framework, and using `System.Numerics.Complex.Conjugate()` returns an error (of course, I can't convert an image into a complex number).

How can I do this ? Is using loops and working pixel-by-pixel the only way ? This seems really tedious and time-consuming. Or is there a way to implement the cross-correlation without using a complex conjugate ?

Comment: For a purely real image in the spatial domain the complex conjugate is the same as the original.

Comment: @PaulR This is so painfully obvious... Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the idiotic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paul R stated, "For a purely real image in the spatial domain the complex conjugate is the same as the original".